Inference Table for a MosaicAI Foundation Model
I am using a MosaicAI Foundation Model, which has automatically been deployed on my Azure Databricks workspace (specifically the Meta Llama 3.1 70B Instruct model). I want to set up Human Evaluation, but it requires an Inference Table. Is there a way to enable this for this type of model?


I managed to find some documentation on this, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/machine-learning/model-serving/inference-tables#limitations

For endpoints that host foundation models, inference tables are only supported on provisioned throughput workloads.

